# How can I sort an array alphanumerically when some values have dots?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I would love to know how to sort this kind  of values :

```
let sizesArray = 

    [
      "Size : US 5.5Y (EU 38)",
      "Size : US 6.5Y (EU 39)",
      "Size : US 4.5Y (EU 36.5)",
      "Size : US 6Y (EU 38.5)",
      "Size : US 7Y (EU 40)",
      "Size : US 4Y (EU 36)",
    ]
```

I sorted it that way :

```
// Create rules for sorting product sizes.
const sortAlphaNum = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true})

// Sorting product Sizes.
let sortedSizes = sizesArray.sort(sortAlphaNum);
```

result :

```
[
   "Size : US 4.5Y (EU 36.5)",
   "Size : US 4Y (EU 36)",    
   "Size : US 5.5Y (EU 38)",  
   "Size : US 6.5Y (EU 39)",  
   "Size : US 6Y (EU 38.5)",  
   "Size : US 7Y (EU 40)"
]
```

As you can see, 4Y is sorted after 4.5Y !
Just because when it compares 4"**Y**" with 4"**.**"5Y,
the dot is before all alphas. how to do the invert ?

Formats I also use :

```
"US 5.5 (EU 38)"
"US 5.5Y (EU 38)"
"W US 9.5 / US 8 (EU 41)"
"US 4.5 (EU 36 2/3)"
```

It works for all but the second one.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings are always in this format, you can use a little regex to parse out the numbers and compare them as numbers instead of as strings.

```js
let sizesArray = [
  "Size : US 5.5Y (EU 38)",
  "Size : US 6.5Y (EU 39)",
  "Size : US 4.5Y (EU 36.5)",
  "Size : US 6Y (EU 38.5)",
  "Size : US 7Y (EU 40)",
  "Size : US 4Y (EU 36)",
]


sizesArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return +a.match(/US\s([\d\.]*)/)[1] - +b.match(/US\s([\d\.]*)/)[1];
});

console.log(sizesArray);
```

PS. [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) will sort you array *in place*, so it doesn't make a lot f sense to allocate memory to a new variable that will refer to the same array as the original variable:

```
// sortedSizes === sizesArray
// Both arrays are exactly the same object
let sortedSizes = sizesArray.sort(sortAlphaNum)
```

Comment: Isn't it right to use '-'? 
' return a.match(/US\s([\d\.]*)/)[1] - b.match(/US\s([\d\.]*)/)[1]; '

Comment: @zoecode - "true" is always cast to 1 and false is always cast to 0, so it works fine to return a boolean.

Comment: It is better to use subtraction. The sort callback is intended to return a negative value when `a` should be sorted before `b`.

Comment: @odelvaux, what do you mean by "the second one?" Can you provide a data set that does not work with the given method?

Comment: You are comparing a number with a string. Did you intend  `+b`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've implemented them in my answer.

Comment: Does your regex will work with all the other formats @Iwrestledabearonce. ?

Comment: As long as there is the letters "US", followed by a space, followed by a floating point number, the regex will work.

Comment: This is exactely what I was  looking for ! You're the best guys ♥ !